# Why the code is giving me error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"?

Tags: javascript, function

**While executing the below code, getting Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token {**

```
const a = function(x,y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  getX(){
    return this.x;
  }

  getY(){
    return this.y;
  }


};

const newA = new a( '1', '2' );

console.log( newA.getX() );
console.log( newA.getY() );
```

*Expected Result : 1 2*

Comment: `getX(){` - there is no `function` keyword here, so by `getX()` you can only mean a function _call_. A `{` directly after a function call makes no sense syntactically however.

Comment: @04FS alternatively, OP meant to use the `class` syntax but this is not in a `class` block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is valid for ES6+ [`class` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class):

```js
class a {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  getX() {
    return this.x;
  }

  getY() {
    return this.y;
  }
};

const newA = new a('1', '2');

console.log(newA.getX());
console.log(newA.getY());
```

If you are using a normal `function`, then you need to assign the properties explicitly:

```js
const a = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.getX = function() {
    return this.x;
  }

  this.getY = function() {
    return this.y;
  }
};

const newA = new a('1', '2');

console.log(newA.getX());
console.log(newA.getY());
```

Or use a prototype, so every instance of `a` will use the same methods, instead of making one set *per instance*:

```js
const a = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

a.prototype.getX = function() {
  return this.x;
}

a.prototype.getY = function() {
  return this.y;
}


const newA = new a('1', '2');

console.log(newA.getX());
console.log(newA.getY());
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions need to be assigned as properties, [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_methods):

```js
const a = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.getX = function() {
    return this.x;
  }

  this.getY = function() {
    return this.y;
  }


};

const newA = new a('1', '2');

console.log(newA.getX());
console.log(newA.getY());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using class syntax inside a function.

You can create a constructor function and add the methods to `a.prototype`

```js
function a(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

a.prototype.getX = function() {
  return this.x;
}

a.prototype.getY = function() {
  return this.y;
}
const newA = new a('1', '2');

console.log(newA.getX());
console.log(newA.getY());
```

Or, create a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) like this:

```js
class a {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  getX() {
    return this.x;
  }

  getY() {
    return this.y;
  }
};

const newA = new a('1', '2');

console.log(newA.getX());
console.log(newA.getY());
```

Another option is to create a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods) for `X` an `Y`:

```js
class a {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  get X() {
    return this.x;
  }

  get Y() {
    return this.y;
  }
};

const newA = new a('1', '2');

console.log(newA.X);
console.log(newA.Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how classes work in javascript. There are two ways to do OO in javascript:

#### Traditional, prototype-based OO:

```
// Traditionally javascript does not have classes, but functions can
// behave as constructors if you give it a prototype:

function A (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

A.prototype.getX = function() {return this.x};
A.prototype.getY = function() {return this.y};
```

Alternatively you can use the new `class` syntax:

#### "New" ES6 classes (actually it's quite old now)

```
class A {
    constructor (x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    getX() { return this.x }

    getY() { return this.y }
}
```

---

You are mixing elements of both syntax - which unfortunately results in invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

The syntax:

```
  getX(){
    return this.x;
  }
```

… is for use inside an *object literal* or a *class*, not a function expression.

```js
class A {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  getX() {
    return this.x;
  }

  getY() {
    return this.y;
  }
};

const newA = new A('1', '2');

console.log(newA.getX());
console.log(newA.getY());
```